# What is type mismatch redeclaration of function in c?

Tags: c

This is my code for simple interest using functions:-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()

{
  int a,c;
  float b,d;

  printf("Enter principle value :");
  scanf("%d", &a);
  printf("Enter rate :");
  scanf("%f", &b);
  printf("Enter time:");
  scanf("%d", &c);

  d=si(a,c,b);
  printf("The simple interest is %f", d);
  getch();
 }
 float si(int a, int c, float b)
 {
   float f;
   f=(p*t*r/100);
   return(0);
 }
```

So this is giving a "type mismatch redeclaration of si" as an error from float si.

Comment: Have you looked at any of the other questions about type mismatch redeclaration errors?

Comment: put `float si(int a, int c, float b);` before `int main(void)`. Also `scanf("%d", &t);` typo as `scanf("%d", &c); ?`

Comment: where is the `t` variable?

Comment: Apart from the obvious missing function prototype, that function is doing calculations on variables that don't exist.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, this snippet

```
printf("Enter time:");
scanf("%d", &t);
```

shouldn't work as you haven't declared `t` as an integer, so just declare `t` on the line above like such.

`int a, c, t;`

You also didn't declare any of the variables in your `si` function. When you pass the `c` variable, it never gets initialized.

What will help your type mismatch error is a forward declaration of the `si` function.

By adding the line `float si(int a, int c, float b);` to the top of your program (above main), you let the compiler know what type of function `si` is, as well as what arguments to expect.

Here is my best attempt to fix up the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

float si(int a, int c, float b);

float si(int a, int c, float b){
    float f;
    f=(a*b*c/100);
    return f;
 }

void main(){
    int a, c;
    float b, d;

    printf("Enter principle value :");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("Enter rate :");
    scanf("%f", &b);
    printf("Enter time:");
    scanf("%d", &c);

    d = si(a,c,b);
    printf("The simple interest is %f", d);
}
```

Comment: As far as i know, there are two types of functions:
In line - where the function is declared before
Prototype - where function is mentioned later
so i followed the latter, then why should it show an error

Comment: @rokkopavka: Because you are compiling in C90 mode (not C99 or C11), your compiler interprets `si(a, c, b)` as a call to a previously undeclared function with an unspecified argument list and a return type of `int` — effectively `extern int si();`.  When you later define `si` as returning a `float`, the compiler complains that the definition does not match the implicit declaration used earlier.  If you are compiling in C99 or C11 mode, you have to declare functions before using them, or you can define a `static` function without a prior prototype.

Comment: @rokkopavka No, there are _function declarations_ and _function definitions_ (the actual function). At the point where a function is called in the program, its format must be known, either through function declaration or function definition located higher up in the source code file than the code calling that function.

Comment: @rokkopavka A function prototype is a function declaration where all the types of the parameters have been declared. It doesn't make any sense to not use prototype format when doing a function declaration, though C allows it for ancient backwards-compatibility reasons. Similarly, old and bad versions of C allowed function declarations that didn't specify a return type - it would instead default to `int`. You are using a compiler that is using such an old, bad version of C. Inline functions is something else entirely and not related to this question.

Answer (score 1):

When you call

```
d = si(a,c,b);
```

your program doesn't know of that function, because it's defined afterwards at the bottom. Look up "forward declaration" to fix this. Also, you use the variable 't' but I can't see it defined.